# PayPal adaptive payment success function

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to sandbox and paypal payment gateway. I am using paypal adaptive payment to pay amount to two people at a time. My current code works perfectly. I am using the paypal generated code. I just want to know that is it possible that when the payment is made successfully can I make that entry to my database. I have my php code, but where do I need to write this?

Thanks in advance(plzz no down votes)

Comment: I answered a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078279/send-email-when-paypal-payment-is-made/10078732#10078732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the IPN message that contain details about the payment status

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

You need to define the url of the php script that listen for those messages in your paypal account. There are some php examples on how to implement it.

Comment: @David Nguyen I just went through this code https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

I understood the php codes, but where and when to call this script?

Comment: Paypal talks to the script when a payment is complete

Comment: @David Nguyen Ya but I need to call this file somewhere? but where? So that the script will be executed. Currently I am using the adaptive parallel payment code which is generated by paypal

Comment: @Nick you don't call it, Paypal does like I said. Read the documentation.

Comment: @David Nguyen OK so I just need to enter the file URL in the paypal Test Tools IPN API, this URL will be the filepath of the IPN file. Am I rite?

Comment: @Nick, you are right. In the sandbox environment you can send your ipn file fake payment messages to test your script. but you still need to define the url in your paypal account so for every transaction you will automatically revive a payment notification